# C++ equivalent of Java's andThen() function to composite new function

Tags: c++

In Java, you can do the following code:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> times2 = e -> e * 2;
Function<Integer, Integer> squared = e -> e * e; 
times2.andThen(squared).apply(4);
```

What's C++'s equivalent of `andThen()` to coin/composite new functors? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't one.  You'll have to find a library or build it yourself.

Comment: Does this question address your need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071268/function-composition-in-c-c11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using Boost, then Boost.HOF is what you need. HOF (Higher order functions) provides the `compose` function adapter with the following semantics

```
assert(compose(f, g)(xs...) == f(g(xs...)));
```

In your case, you will do

```
auto composed = compose(squared, times2);
auto result = composed(4);
```

Have a look at the documentation for details https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/compose.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep things simple?

```
int times2thenSquared(int x) {
    x = times2(x);
    return squared(x);
}
```

(can do it with lambda as well, if you want)